# overflow-x visible and overflow-y scroll / auto fail in chrome

Tags: css, html, styles, overflow

I have a `div` and I want it to be scrollable just vertically but visible horizontally.
I decide to set it's overlowX to visible and it's overflowY to scroll and it works well in IE8, Firefox, but not in Chrome.

Here is what I did to my div

```
<div id="myDiv" style="overflow-x:visible; overflow-y:scroll">
</div>
```

Anyone knows how to fix it or having another solution to make my div to be as what I want?

Comment: Setting your overflow-y to scroll will introduce the scrollbar, which blocks content from flowing past it. Can you create a fiddle or codepen to illustrate your problem? http://jsfiddle.net/Vt4nm/1/

Comment: I try to simulate it:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vt4nm/4/

Comment: That works fine there...actually i want to make a kind of fixed header table... but the problem i mean doesn't appear in simulation..i don't know why... The div2's width in my chrome page appearing a scrollx. But also my second question:how to make the every header column width same with it's content's width? the header has been set same width with it's content but when data load the width is messy netween header and content